# Recyclerview Onclick() doesnt open the desired activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I have a chatroom application in which all the chatrooms are displayed in the homepage.When the user clicks on the chatroom it opens a activity where more data about the chatroom is displayed.When I have more than one chatroom and when I click on any of the chatroom it always just opens one specific chatroom and shows it details.For example,If I open chatroom 1 it shows the details of chatroom 2 and if I click on any chatrooms from 1 to 5 it always just shows the data of chatroom one.When the user clicks on the item a documentid id passed to the activity and then in that activity data is retrieved from firebase.

**My JAVA CODE for recycleView Activity**

```
public class Homepage extends Fragment  {


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    String documentid;
    private List<model> list;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);


        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref = database.getReference().child("Chatrooms").child("chatroomdata");
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot npsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        model l = npsnapshot.getValue(model.class);
                        list.add(l);
                    }
                    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(list);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error!" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });






        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),createchatroom.class));
            }
        });


        return v;








    }

    public static class model{
       String Image,numberofviewers,numberofusers,adminid,allowviewers,descriptionget,title,type,documentid;

        public String getImage() {
            return Image;
        }

        public model(){

        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.Image = Image;
        }

        public String getNumberofviewers() {
            return numberofviewers;
        }

        public void setNumberofviewers(String numberofviewers) {
            this.numberofviewers = numberofviewers;
        }

        public String getNumberofusers() {
            return numberofusers;
        }

        public void setNumberofusers(String numberofusers) {
            this.numberofusers = numberofusers;
        }

        public String getAdminid() {
            return adminid;
        }

        public void setAdminid(String adminid) {
            this.adminid = adminid;
        }

        public String getAllowviewers() {
            return allowviewers;
        }

        public void setAllowviewers(String allowviewers) {
            this.allowviewers = allowviewers;
        }

        public String getDescriptionget() {
            return descriptionget;
        }

        public void setDescriptionget(String descriptionget) {
            this.descriptionget = descriptionget;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getDocumentid() {
            return documentid;
        }

        public void setDocumentid(String documentid) {
            this.documentid = documentid;
        }

        public model(String Image, String numberofviewers, String numberofusers, String adminid, String allowviewers, String descriptionget, String title, String type, String documentid) {
            this.Image = Image;
            this.numberofviewers = numberofviewers;
            this.numberofusers = numberofusers;
            this.adminid = adminid;
            this.allowviewers = allowviewers;
            this.descriptionget = descriptionget;
            this.title = title;
            this.type = type;
            this.documentid = documentid;
        }
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{
        private List<model> list;

        public MyAdapter(List<model> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatroomrecyclerdesign,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            model ld = list.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(ld.getTitle());
            holder.viewers.setText(ld.getNumberofviewers());
            documentid = ld.getDocumentid();
            String url = ld.getImage();

            if (url.equals("noimage")){
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.grouppic).into(holder.circleImageView);
            }else {
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(holder.circleImageView);
            }



        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            private TextView title,viewers;
            CircleImageView circleImageView;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatroomtitlerecycler);
                viewers=itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatroomviewersrecycler);
                circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatroomdisplayimagerecycler);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent data = new Intent(getActivity(), joinclassroom.class);
                        data.putExtra("documentid",documentid);
                        startActivity(data);
                    }
                });


            }
        }
    }





}
```

**The activity that shows the details of the chatroom.**

```
public class joinclassroom extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    CircleImageView circleImageView;
    TextView title,description,users,viewers,type,full;
    Button join,spectate;
    String imageurl;
    int numberofchatters;
    String password,nameString,imageString;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    int getNumberofchatters = 0;
    int numberofviewers;
    String clickSpectate = "spectate";
    DatabaseReference usersnumberchatroom;
    int kitneusers = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_joinclassroom);


        join = findViewById(R.id.joinclassroombtn);
        full = findViewById(R.id.full);
        circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.groupdisplayimage);
        title = findViewById(R.id.title);
        final String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        description = findViewById(R.id.description);
        users = findViewById(R.id.numberofusers);
        viewers = findViewById(R.id.numberofviewers);
        type = findViewById(R.id.type);
        spectate = findViewById(R.id.spectate);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Joining");
        final DatabaseReference user = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("profiledata").child(user_id);





        user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                imageString = snapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue().toString();
                nameString = snapshot.child("Full name").getValue().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


        imageView = findViewById(R.id.close);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String s = i.getStringExtra("documentid");




        usersnumberchatroom = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chatrooms").child("chatroomdata");
usersnumberchatroom.child(s).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String kitneusers1 = snapshot.child("number of users").getValue().toString();
        kitneusers = Integer.parseInt(kitneusers1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
        spectate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent spectate = new Intent(joinclassroom.this,chatroom.class);
                spectate.putExtra("spectate",clickSpectate);
                startActivity(spectate);

                numberofviewers++;
                reference.child("numberofviewers").setValue(String.valueOf(numberofviewers));
            }
        });

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chatrooms").child("chatroomdata").child(s);

        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                title.setText(snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString());
                description.setText(snapshot.child("descriptionget").getValue().toString());
                users.setText(snapshot.child("number of users").getValue().toString() + "/10");
                viewers.setText(snapshot.child("numberofviewers").getValue().toString());
                type.setText(snapshot.child("type").getValue().toString());

                if (snapshot.child("allowviewers").getValue().toString().equals("dontallowviewers")) {
                    spectate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewers.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                    spectate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spectate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), chatroom.class));
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (snapshot.child("type").getValue().toString().equals("Private")) {
                    password = snapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
                    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("password", password);
                    bundle.putString("chatroomidprivate", s);

                    join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            progressDialog.show();
                            DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chatrooms").child("members").child(s);
                            Map<String, Object> memberadd = new HashMap<>();
                            memberadd.put("name", nameString);
                            memberadd.put("Image", imageString);
                            memberadd.put("id", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                            reference1.child(user_id).setValue(memberadd).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    getNumberofchatters++;
                                    reference.child("numberofusers").setValue(String.valueOf(getNumberofchatters));
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    bottomsheet bottomsheet = new bottomsheet();
                                    bottomsheet.setArguments(bundle);
                                    bottomsheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "bottomsheet");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chatrooms").child("members").child(s);
                            Map<String, Object> memberadd = new HashMap<>();
                            memberadd.put("name", nameString);
                            memberadd.put("Image", imageString);
                            memberadd.put("id", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                            reference1.child(user_id).setValue(memberadd).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    getNumberofchatters++;
                                    reference.child("numberofusers").setValue(String.valueOf(getNumberofchatters));
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(joinclassroom.this, chatroom.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("chatroomidpublic", s);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
                numberofchatters = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("number of users").getValue().toString());

                if (numberofchatters >= 10) {
                    join.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    full.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    full.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    join.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                imageurl = snapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();

                if (imageurl.equals("noimage")) {

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.grouppic).into(circleImageView);

                } else {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageurl).into(circleImageView);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 450 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

Modified here in your code

```js
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent data = new Intent(getActivity(), joinclassroom.class);
                        data.putExtra("documentid",documentid);
                        getActivity().startActivity(data);
                    }
                });
```